# Importing multiple csv files and add year to each file

Tags: r, csv, dplyr

I'm using the following function to import roughly 10 files from different years (all from the same folder) into r.

```
ed.attain.places_0_10_18 <-
    list.files(path = "./ed_attainment/",
               pattern = "*.csv", 
               full.names = T) %>% 
    map_df(~read_csv(., col_types = cols(.default = "c")))
```

This folder (ed_attainment/) contains the following csv files all the way to '17.

```
ACS_09_5YR_B19301_with_ann.csv
ACS_10_5YR_B19301_with_ann.csv
```

I want to add the year to each one of these files within the above function. Just importing one csv file the code would be

```
read_csv("ACS_09_5YR_B19301_with_ann.csv")%>%mutate(year = 09)
```

such that the year in the filename corresponds with the values in the new "year" variable.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this but without changing much of your code, you can add an id variable named `year` in `map_df` which will have index of the filename. So first file (`ACS_09_5YR_B19301_with_ann.csv`) would have index as 1, second file (`ACS_10_5YR_B19301_with_ann.csv`) would have index as 2 and so on.

You can then add 2008 to this index to get year value from 2009-2017.

```
list.files(path = "./ed_attainment/",
           pattern = "\\.csv", 
           full.names = TRUE) %>% 
    purrr::map_df(~readr::read_csv(.,col_types = cols(.default = "c")), 
                 .id ='year') %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(year = 2008 + as.integer(year))
```

Comment: Awesome! and then if I wanted to remove the header would I just insert ```%>%slice(-1)``` after the as.integer(year))

Comment: `slice(-1)` would remove the first row from the combined data. By header do you mean you want to remove the column names?

Comment: Yes, there are two rows with column names in each file, and I want the second one.

Comment: Also, just a quick follow-up question--if one file is out of sync (like '15 is between '11 and '13, or if there is a year missing) is there a workaround for that?

Comment: You can extract the year name from the file name or just add `%>%
    gtools::mixedsort() %>%` between `list.files` and `map_df`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
myReadCsv <- function(fullPath){
   # Pull the Year out of the fullPath
  year <- paste0("20", str_match(fullPath, 
                         "ACS_(\\d{2})")[,2])
    # Read csv as you did before
  read_csv(fullPath, col_types = cols(.default = "c")) %>% 
     # Add YEAR in as a column
    mutate(YEAR = year)
}
```

and then

```
ed.attain.places_0_10_18 <-
  list.files(path = "./ed_attainment/",
             pattern = "*.csv", 
             full.names = T) %>% 
  map_df(myReadCsv)
```

### NOT RUN

## Because I don't have a directory of CSV files handy. ##